# How to represent a double in a boolector model?

Tags: smt

I have a boolector model where the variable `x` has value `0x1000`, now I would like to understand if it is possible to represent a number as a floating point or not. If yes can I have an example showing how I should do it please?

Thanks

Comment: *AFAIK*, boolector does not seem to support the Floating Point SMT-LIB Theory yet. The idea of reducing FP to BV within the formula sounds dreadful to me. So you may want to try other smt solvers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I confirmed with the boolector team that the fp theory is not supported atm.